# HTML5 DOCTYPE obsolete?

Tags: html, doctype, coda

I use Coda from Panic Inc for my coding.
I just coded a regular HTML form using HTML5.
At the top I have my doctype declared (ofcourse!) like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It is completely fine according to the W3 validator

But if I use the validator in Coda I get this message:

> This interface to HTML5 document checking is obsolete. Use an interface to https://validator.w3.org/nu/ instead.
>
> The method you used to check this document relies on an obsolete interface
>                           that will become permanently unavailable in the near future.

Now I am wondering what this means as I have not found much info on this.
Anyone an idea of how or why this message is there?
As far as I know doctype is still required to create a reliable webpage.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the doctype, but about the validator.

The validator Coda is connecting to, `validate.w3.org`, has been deprecated in favour of `validator.w3.org/nu/`.

See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716156/this-interface-to-html5-document-checking-is-deprecated-whats-the-meaning)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Missed it in my search on Google.